# Pandas apply function returning larger Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a 'test' Dataframe of length 1821 with just one column and would like to format the strings of just the first 50 values. I made a function to do this:

```
def format_some_paths():
    test_paths = test[:50]
    print(test_paths.shape)
    test_paths = test_paths.apply(format_path)
```

This is the format_path function:

```
def format_path(st):
    return "../input/plant-pathology-2020-fgvc7/images/" + st + '.jpg'
```

Now after doing this, the shape of the resulting test_values Dataframe is (1821,), *even though* the print statement in the first function returns (50,1). So I am taking a Column of length 50, applying a simple function, and it is giving me back a Column of length 1821. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: This might seem like a dumb question but are you returning test_paths? This might be a scoping issue

Comment: I believe that was it. I didn't think I needed to return it since test_paths wasn't called or defined anywhere else